# How do I tell sympy that ∂b[a]/∂b==1? Derivative on IndexedBase

Tags: sympy

I have an expression which includes an `IndexedBase`.  I'm taking a partial derivative, but in the output, this is retained:

```
In [105]: sympy.IndexedBase(b)[a].diff(b)
Out[105]: 
∂       
──(b[a])
∂b
```

My `b[a]` is simply an array `b_0`, `b_1`, ..., `b_n`.  Those are all constants, so ∂b[a]/∂b is equal to 1.  How do I rephrase my problem such that it evaluates to one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, install the latest [**master branch**](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/tree/master) of SymPy (the **latest** SymPy version **doesn't support** these features). Otherwise wait for the next SymPy version release.

Anyway, you can get a Kronecker delta function:

```
In [27]: b = IndexedBase("b")

In [28]: b[a].diff(b[c])
Out[28]: 
δ   
 a,c
```

If you derive the indexed object by the same index:

```
In [29]: b[a].diff(b[a])
Out[29]: 1
```

The operation `b[a].diff(b)` isn't clearly defined though, and will raise an error.

I would personally interpret `b[a].diff(b)` as an array of derivatives *∂b[a]/∂b[0], ∂b[a]/∂b[1], ...*